# Polytope in $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ such that every point is a convex combination of at most $\ell< m$ vertices

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, linear-programming, convex-geometry, polyhedra

We know that every point in a polytope is either a vertex or can be represented by a convex combination of vertices.

But my question is: are there polytopes in $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ such that every point can be represented with fewer than $m$ vertices. Better yet, on the order of $O(\sqrt{m})$ vertices, and ideally less than or equal to $\sqrt{m}$ vertces

Do such polytopes/polyhedra have name, or any other refernces on the smallest number of vertices needed to represent a point inside a polyhedron will be appreciated!

Comment: I think Caratheodory's Theorem applies here.

Comment: Thanks! I should edit the question mentioning that the verctors are in $\mathbb{R}^n,$ so I need strictly less than the dimension points.

Comment: Your question asks about the number of vertices, not the dimension of the space.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_theorem_(convex_hull) Carathéodory's theorem is a theorem in convex geometry. It states that if a point x of $R^d$ lies in the convex hull of a set P, then x can be written as the convex combination of at most $d + 1$ points in P.

Comment: Yes, thank you! Rewrote the whole question.

Comment: So now you want a polygon in $R^2$ such that every point is a vertex? In $R^3$, you want every point to lie on an edge or a face or body diagonal? You want every point in an $m$-dimensional solid to be in the union of finitely many lower-dimensional objects? Can't happen.

Comment: Have you given up on this question?

Comment: No, I haven't. I think I am just looking for polyhedra in $\mathbb{R}^m$ with less than $m$ vertices. This should be fine.

Comment: Any subset of ${\bf R}^m$ with fewer than $m$ elements is contained in a (vector) subspace of dimension less than $m$. Again, think of two vertices in three dimensions.

Comment: Yes, that's true, thanks.

Comment: Technically, you can have an $(m-1)$-dimensional polytope embedded in $\Bbb R^m$, which then satisfies your condition. But I am not sure that this is what you are looking for.